# How to save/cache the dom so that the page loads as-is when you hit the back button?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, web-deployment, bfcache

i add models to my js app model collection using ajax calls. when i click a model and go to the next page, i want all the models i had loaded to still be there when i hit the back button. what is the best way to do this so that it works on all browsers? this is for mobile web. i can't find a straight answer, how do i use bfcache, or js history, or is there another, better way?

Comment: At least firefox actually restores the page verbatim (DOM and javascript state) if it's still in the bfcache, unless that has been suppressed by certain event handlers.

Comment: i don't think anyone will be using FF on mobile though, trying to get this to work on safari and chrome mostly for ios and android mobile web users

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in the local Storage and ajax for them only if the do not exist on the local Storage

So instead of using the regular $.ajax , use this for the ajax that you want cached:

```
function storageBasedAjax(url,cb){

    if (localStorage.getItem("myAxaxCache_"+url)){
      cb(localStorage.getItem("myAxaxCache_"+url));
      return;
    }       

   $.ajax({url: url, success: function(result){
     localStorage.setItem("myAxaxCache_"+url,result);
        cb(result);
   }});
}
```

Just remember you do not want to over load, so if you have a url with a  parameter changing each call,do not use this or you will overload the local storage

Comment: I'm pretty sure the browser doesn't save Ajax content when using back button by default.

Comment: It saves it on cash, not related to back button.

Comment: browser currently doesnt save anything on mobile safari on ios

Comment: @PatO'Keefe I said might. Anyway my main solution is local storage and it's a good one.

Comment: what is the best way to save the dom to local storage? @O_Z i didnt down vote

Comment: @PatO'Keefe I think you should only save your ajax results and re-render. On your ajax function just check the storage and if it's there just return it and do not do the ajax.It will be very fast

Comment: @O_Z do you mean using hmtl localStorage? or something else? also thank you very much for the responses

Comment: @PatO'Keefe i will write it soon in my post.

Comment: @PatO'Keefe check my code, I tested it, it works.An up vote will be nice

Comment: @O_Z i tried to upvote but i have less than 15 reputation so it says it won't publicly display i'm sorry :(((((( but thank you very much i will see if that works!

Comment: i cant figure out what that code means, i'm going to look into history.js and pushstate popstate etc